# Is this the appropriate redux state when grouping items together

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a reducer(let's say allpeople-reducer.js) in my redux that is resposible for the below piece of state

```
    {
      1:{id:1, first_name: "Tony", last_name: "Stark", gender: "Male"}

      2:{id:2,first_name: "Wonder", last_name: "Woman", gender: "Female"}

      3:{id:3,first_name: "Bruce", last_name: "Wayne", gender: "Male"}

      4:{id:4,first_name: "Thor", last_name: "Ragnarok", gender: "Male"}

      5:{id:5,first_name: "Bruce", last_name: "Banner", gender: "Male"}

      6:{id:6,first_name: "Aqua", last_name: "Man", gender: "Male"}

      7:{id:7,first_name: "Bat", last_name: "Girl", gender: "Female"}

      8:{id:8,first_name: "Me", last_name: "Mario", gender: "MALE"}
   }
```

As you can see I have converted an array into Object of arrays with id as my key. User then can select people in the UI and build some groups from the above people list. I now have to include group number for each person. So can I convert the above piece of state to below

```
   {
      1:{id:1, first_name: "Tony", last_name: "Stark", gender: "Male", group: 1}

      2:{id:2,first_name: "Wonder", last_name: "Woman", gender: "Female", group:2}

      3:{id:3,first_name: "Bruce", last_name: "Wayne", gender: "Male", group:3}
      4:{}......
  }
```

My intention is to show people belonging to same group together using react components. So if I have three groups, I will show three components, that display all the people of a group together in each component, using react-redux. Please let me know if I have got this right.

Comment: You should always keep your state clean, meaning in this case you should keep all the people together, but use a selector to get the people you want based on the group id

Comment: Hi, Arber Sylejmani, yes, I am keeping all the people together. But can I add group as a new key to my previous state. I can use selector only if I have the group. My initial state has no group, but as soon as user adds a person to the group, i update my state(carefully by copying to new state) Hope you understood.

Comment: Create a new piece of state holding just the group ids then use the selectors to compute derived data from the store. For example:

state.allPeople = {...} and state.groups = ['1','2','3',...]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated. My state will be same, but once user adds a person to UI, I am updating the person info to include groupid in my reducer.

Comment: Then when a user adds a person, you update both pieces of state, allPeople where you actually add the person, and also groups but you should check if (state.groups.indexOf(group) === -1) add group, as you don't need duplicate group ids

Comment: and yes, each person should have the group id

Comment: It makes sense now! Thank you for your time, Arber!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for something more like a code review rather than an answer to a specific question. I am not sure if SO is the right place to do this, but here goes:

- It's rather strange that you are maintaining an object whose keys are basically indices. That's basically a poor recreation of the Javascript array object. Why not just store the hero entries in an array.
- At some point, you are going to have to segregate the hero entries on the basis of groups. You *could* do it in the component itself, though that may cause performance issues if the component is re-rendered often. I would rather do it in the reducer and store the segregated structure in the state store.
- As other people mentioned, you could also use selectors to compute the segregation while keeping the state store as a linear array of heroes. I reckon this would be more efficient but do not try optimizing without doing some actual measurements for your specific use case.
- You are conflating two different superhero universes. ;)

If you do indeed decide to do it in the component, your code will look something like below. (I tested the code [in a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4qxrqyj5w7), so you can see it working there.)

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const heroes = {
  '1': { id: 1, first_name: 'Tony', last_name: 'Stark', gender: 'Male', group: 1 },
  '2': { id: 2, first_name: 'Wonder', last_name: 'Woman', gender: 'Female', group: 2 },
  '3': { id: 3, first_name: 'Bruce', last_name: 'Wayne', gender: 'Male', group: 3 },
  '4': { id: 4, first_name: 'Thor', last_name: 'Ragnarok', gender: 'Male', group: 1 },
  '5': { id: 5, first_name: 'Bruce', last_name: 'Banner', gender: 'Male', group: 2 },
  '6': { id: 6, first_name: 'Aqua', last_name: 'Man', gender: 'Male', group: 3 },
  '7': { id: 7, first_name: 'Bat', last_name: 'Girl', gender: 'Female', group: 1 },
  '8': { id: 8, first_name: 'Me', last_name: 'Mario', gender: 'MALE', group: 2 },
};

const segregateGroups = consolidatedHeroes => {
  return Object.keys(consolidatedHeroes).reduce((groups, key) => {
    const currentHero = consolidatedHeroes[key];
    const groupId = currentHero.group - 1;
    if (!groups[groupId]) {
      groups[groupId] = [];
    }
    groups[groupId].push(currentHero);
    return groups;
  }, []);
};


const SuperGroup = (props) => (
  <div>
    <hr />
    <ul>
      {props.heroes.map(hero => (<li id={hero.id}>{hero.first_name} {hero.last_name}</li>))}
    </ul>
    <hr />
  </div>
);

const SuperHeroConsolidated = (props) => (
  <div>
    {segregateGroups(props.heroes).map(group => (<SuperGroup heroes={group} />))}
  </div>
);

render(<SuperHeroConsolidated heroes={heroes} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```